# html: wrong footer placement: inner div is bigger than outer div

Tags: html, css

I have following layout structure:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="head"></div>
    <div id="columns">
        <div id="menu"></div>   
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>            
    <div id="foot">
        <div id="copyright"></div>
        <div id="username"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with this css:

```
div#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top: 20px;
    width:1000px;    
}

div#head {
    position: absolute;
    width:1000px;
    height:50px;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px;
}

div#columns {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    top: 50px;      
}

div#menu {
    position:absolute;
    width:250px;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
}

div#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 750px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 250px;
}

div#foot {      
    position: absolute;
    width: 1000px;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

The issue is, that the footer is displayed "to high up" in the page and the content - div is "bigger", which means it has stuff below the footer. See:

[image: screenshot]

If i use position: relative for the footer, it is displayed a bit lower but not below columns-div as I would expect. I also tried with clear:both but that does not change anything.

I'm not a css expert so can someone post a solution and explain why the footer is displayed in this way?

Comment: Why are you absolutely positioning the divs?

Comment: check to this http://tinkerbin.com/38CF0j5b

Comment: @DaveHogan Head and foot should always be at top and bottom of page? But it seems this does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, DaveHogans comments lead me to following solution:

```
div#wrapper {    
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top: 20px;
    width:1000px;   
}

div#head {
    position: relative;
    width:1000px;
    height:50px;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px;
}

div#columns {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
}

div#menu {
    position:absolute;
    width:250px;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
}

div#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 750px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 250px;
}

div#foot {  
    clear:both;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    padding-top: 10px;  
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>

div#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top: 20px;
    width:1000px;    
}

div#head {
    position: absolute;
    width:1000px;
    height:50px;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px;
}

div#columns {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    top: 50px;      
}

div#menu {
    position:absolute;
    width:250px;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
}

div#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 750px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 250px;
}

div#foot {
    margin-top:25px;   
    width: auto;
  }

    </style>


 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="head"></div>
    <div id="columns">
        <div id="menu"></div>   
        <div id="content"></div> <div id="foot">
        <div id="copyright">Footer</div>
        <div id="username"></div>
    </div>
    </div>            

</div>
```

Comment: margin-top on the footer depends on the content. Sometimes 50px is enough other times you need 100px. So basically can't use that solution.